# Why is this RPM graph squarewave?

Tags: subaru, rpm, electronic-control-module, diagnostics

'07 Subaru Outback 3.0R 5 speed auto.  I am logging using the excellent RomRaider and was kind of surprised that when graphed RPM looks like a square wave in most situations, don't know if it was doing this before.  The first chart covers 8 seconds at 50 readings per second, the second lower RPM's at 20 readings per seocnd.   Is this normal ?

[image: 50kph, second gear][image]

Comment: I don't believe the plot is "real". I would guess something in the electronics or the sensor has failed giving the nonsense data, and the rough running is the ECU thinking the nonsense *is* real and trying to modulate the fuel flow rate to stop the apparent oscillations, or something similar.

Comment: Can you verify this with another scantool/software?

Comment: Definitely could be a logging/sampling issue.  The car has a drive-line issue so will update here after fixing the car and logging over again.

Comment: maybe due to the way the crankshaft position sensor works reading teeth on the crankshaft plate ?